# How to declare the KeyPress Event Handler in a common way to all TextBoxes?

Tags: c#-4.0

I have 20 TextBoxes in a form. And I have a Common KeyPress Event for all of that Textboxes.

So I try to declare the keypress event like the following manner... is it possible?

```
for (int Cnl = 1; Cnl < 21; Cnl++)
{
   ((RichTextBox)Cnl).KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(this.Comn_KeyPress);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct idea; but casting an int to a RichTextBox will never work.  Try this:

```
 foreach (var control in this.Controls)
 {
     var text = control as RichTextBox;
     if (text != null)
          text.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(this.Comn_KeyPress);
 }
```

Comment: Sorry...It Doesn't...Thanks for The Helps

Comment: @Paramu: you might want to provide a better explanation, than "It doesn't" to improve your chances of getting this resolved.

Answer (score 2):

For a WPF application you can register global event handlers using the methods on the EventManager static class:

```
// Register the following class handlers for the TextBox XxFocus events.
EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(TextBox), TextBox.GotKeyboardFocusEvent, 
    new RoutedEventHandler(HandleTextBoxFocus));
```

Then add whatever logic you need on the event handler, for ex.:

```
    private void HandleTextBoxFocus(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        (sender as TextBox).SelectAll();
    }
```